# How to make Helm always add ^ to the input pattern

Tags: helm

Is there a way in Helm to first match substrings from the beginning and only after that in the middle of candidates?

For instance, I have the following directory structure:

```
~/
    .emacs.d/
    .gem/
    .microemulator/
```

And I want to open a file in the directory `.emacs.d`. I start to type `.em` and Helm matches `.gem` first.

How to make Helm match `.emacs.d` first, without prepending the beginning of line symbol (`^`)?

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible with a `pattern-transformer`.
Here's a sample code:

```
(helm :sources
          `((name . "Headings")
            (candidates . ,candidates)
            (action . (lambda (x) (goto-char x)
                         (call-interactively 'show-branches)
                         (worf-more)))
            (pattern-transformer . worf--pattern-transformer)))

(defun worf--pattern-transformer (x)
  "Transform X to make 1-9 select the heading level in `worf-goto'."
  (if (string-match "^[1-9]" x)
      (setq x (format "^%s" x))
    x))
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason the character is not included because potentially a filename can contain that character. Btw, you are using the Helm version of `find-file`, not the actual `helm-find-files`. The `helm-find-files` command can fuzzy match, so you can just type "emd" to get to `~/.emacs.d`, and even if you type "em", the command should give you `~/.emacs.d` first. Check the [helm-find-files section](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html#sec-7) in my guide.

Comment: I tried typing `em` and it did match `.emacs.d` first in both `helm-find-files` and `helm-mode`-based `find-file` (didn't know they were different!). Why is it not matching `.em` the same way as `em`?

Comment: @katspaugh The same goes for `helm-M-x` is different from helm-based `M-x`. You can tell by execute persistent action (by default bound to TAB) and see the action menu. `helm-find-files` give you much more, and to know each action does what, read in details in [my Helm Projectile guide, File Management section](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-projectile.html#sec-6)